# Delete users from mailbox rule

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a problem with some script that I want to write. I have for example a TEST rule in local Exchange. There are accounts added manually which are disabled. I'm looking for a way to clear the rule of disabled accounts and leave the enabled accounts as they were. I thought that I will export through Exchange Management Shell a list of people from this rule. Then through foreach and Get-ADUser I will add the missing data and then load the .CSV file once again and based on the email and disabled account I will remove these people from the rule.

I don't know if this is feasible, but I'm trying. I would appreciate any hints on what I am doing wrong in the script.
When I want to run the script, I get the message:

> Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: ' "UserPrincipalName -like
> '$($_.Mail)'" -and "Enabled -eq '$false'"' Error Message: 'syntax
> error' at position: '2'.

Below is my code:

```
<#
The first step is to export the list of users who are in the TEST rule
#>

Get-TransportRule "TEST" | 
select -ExpandProperty "ExceptIfSentTo" | 
Export-Csv -Path C:\TEST.csv -NoTypeInformation


<#
Second, the list of users is displayed and then I add the data of these users such as:
Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled
#>

Import-Csv C:\TEST.csv | foreach {  
Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RawIdentity)'"} | 
  select name, sAMAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled
  
#Export data with attributes to a second .csv file
Import-Csv C:\TEST.csv | foreach {  
Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.RawIdentity)'"} | 
  select name, sAMAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled |
  Export-Csv -Path C:\TEST_with_attributes.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Force

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3


<#Here it wants to load a file and, based on the UserPrinicalName and the fact that the account is disabled, remove users from the TEST rule#>
Import-Csv C:\TEST_with_attributes.csv | foreach {  
Get-ADUser -Filter { "UserPrincipalName -like '$($_.UserPrincipalName)'" -and "Enabled -eq '$false'"} } | Disable-InboxRule "TEST" -AlwaysDeleteOutlookRulesBlob
```